# After formatting server and reinstalling OS WinServer 2019, my Blazor server side app gives Error HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error

Tags: asp.net-core, iis, web-config, blazor-server-side, http-error

I know that there are lot of entries regarding this subject, but as the suggested solutions didn't help yet, I wanted to explain my usecase with its sprecific conditions and narrow the problem:

I have a IIS (V10.0) managed Blazor server side app (.NET7) that was running on a server with OS WinServer2019 without problem. Because of some problems in the Windows OS, our IT dep. has formatted the server and reinstalled WinServer 2019 again. (same version)

Before formatting, I copied the C:\inetpub directory where the file structure of the website exists as backup, and also took screenshots of the IIS settings I have made for the website. The website is running on our company intranet (not in the internet).

After the server was reinstalled, I copied back the directory structure back to folder C:\inetpub and configured the ISS as in the past. Of course first I had to add IIS and the all the related features to windows. Unf. here I am not sure whether I have really added all the needed features of IIS.

At the end I get the Error on the browser:

HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error.
The requested page cannot be accessed because the related configuration data for the page is invalid.

Detailed Error Information:
Module: IIS Web Core
Notification: Unknown
Handler: Not yet determined
Error Code:  0x8007000d
Config Error:-
Config File: \?\C:\inetpub\wmi_asp\web.config

Finaly here my web.config file that is existing under the link above: (no change was made here to the original status)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
<location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
<system.webServer>
  <handlers>
    <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
  </handlers>
  <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\WebApplication7.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" hostingModel="inprocess" />
</system.webServer>
</location>
</configuration>
<!--ProjectGuid: 3d8c75e2-8edd-498a-951e-9a1b564f7282-->
```

Update:1 Additional information

I wanted to open the modules of my website in order to check whether AspNetCoreModuleV2 was existing. But when I double click to modules in IIS I get following Error:

[image]

Comment: You copied quite a few things but unfortunately those are just portion of things IIS might use. For example, ASP.NET Core module bits (and many others) are installed to Program Files. Try to use proper Windows backup mechanism, not such.

Answer (score 0):

After information given in Update-1 I noticed that I had not installed
.NET Core Hosting Bundle on the formatted server. After installing that my webpage opened again.